# Delete a table row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dom

Today i have a question about how i can delete a tablerow.
I have a table where the tablerows are filled with data from the database by a foreach.
Down below you can see the foreach i use the fill the tablerow.

**I would like to have when you select the row by the selectbutton and click a button 'delete' the row will be deleted from the database.
**  I hope someone can help me with this

```
    $oSelect = new creatorwebsite();
    $cWebsites = creatorwebsite::get($oSelect);

foreach($cWebsites as $oWebsite)
    {
      $oTr2 = $oPage->createElement('tr');
      $oTr2->setAttribute('id', $oWebsite->getAttribute("website_id"));
        $oTd = $oPage->createElement('td');
          $oCheckbox = $oPage->createElement('input');
          $oCheckbox->setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
          $oCheckbox->setAttribute('onclick','selectRow(this)');
          $oTd->appendChild($oCheckbox);
        $oTr2->appendChild($oTd);

        $oTd = $oPage->createElement('td', $oWebsite->getAttribute("server_name"));
        $oTr2->appendChild($oTd);
        $oTd = $oPage->createElement('td', $oWebsite->getAttribute("klantnaam"));
        $oTr2->appendChild($oTd);
        $oTd = $oPage->createElement('td', $oWebsite->getAttribute("startdatum")->format('Y-m-d'));
        $oTr2->appendChild($oTd);
        $oTd = $oPage->createElement('td', $oWebsite->getAttribute("quota"));
        $oTr2->appendChild($oTd);
        $oTd = $oPage->createElement('td', $oWebsite->getAttribute("status"));
        $oTr2->appendChild($oTd);
        $oTd = $oPage->createElement('td', '(Edit)');
        $oTd->setAttribute('class','editAction');
        $oTd->setAttribute('id','editButton');

        $oTr2->appendChild($oTd);
      $oTable->appendChild($oTr2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ajax

> $( document ).ready(function() {
>
> var id = $("your_id").val();
>
> $("your_button").click(function(){
>
> > $.ajax({
> >
> > ```
> >         type : "POST",
> >        url  : "delete.php",
> >        data : "id=" + id,
> >        error : function(){
> > ```
>
> ```
>        },
>        success : function(response){
>   if(response == 'success'){
>       location.reload();  
>    }      
>        }
>    });
> ```
>
> > ```
> > });
> > ```
> >
> > });
> >
> > delete.php
> >     establish your db connection and
> >     do the delete process here in this page and echo result "sucess or failure".

Comment: Don't i have to do anything with the selectbox so it knows wich row is selected??

Comment: if you want to do it with select box ,you can use change() function instead of click()